# cakePHP - how do I conditionally load a component into a controller?

Tags: cakephp

I'm using the great Facebook plugin for cakephp 1.3 by http://www.webtechnick.com. This is what I have at the moment:

```
class UsersController extends AppController {
    var $name = 'Users';
    var $components = array('Facebook.Connect');

    function beforeFilter {
        $this->set('facebookUser', $this->Connect->user());
    }
}
```

But I want to load the Facebook.Connect component conditionally, and use it in the controller - something like this in sudocode...

```
if ($thisIsTrue) {
    Load_the_component_and_make_it_ready_for_use;
    $this->set('facebookUser', $this->Connect->user());
}
```

How should I do this?

Comment: http://book.cakephp.org/view/939/Loading-Components

Comment: Good question.  I'm trying to do this too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the Component is initialized while loading with the controller I wouldn't recommend loading it later on.

Like maggie commented you could load the component ( http://book.cakephp.org/view/939/Loading-Components ) but then you'd have to call startup and initialize yourself and attach the object to your controller.

All in all it might be easier to just make the $this->set... conditional and let the component load every time.

Comment: The problem with letting the component load every time is that, if the user is logged in Facebook I can't log them out of my site because the component syncs facebook with the Auth component and logs the user back in. One answer is to log the user out of facebook first, but that's not the behaviour I want. I could mess with the component but as it is maintained so I don't really want to do that. So I'll try and conditionally attach the object myself. Cheers.

Comment: Ah, the initialize method is defined inside the component - so I'm messing with the component after all...

Comment: So, it turns out that this Facebook.Connect component already has an initialize method. Instead of conditionally attaching the component, I modified the initialize method to conditionally sync the user with Auth (thereby loggin in to site) based on the state of a session var I set on a manual logout from the site.

Comment: FYI, This is not so hard to do in CakePHP 2.0 . Read my answer below

Comment: Link broken 404, please consider adding relevant code to the answer when posting in the future :(

Answer (score 5):

If you are doing this in CakePHP 2.0 it is really easy.  I found this SO thread which discouraged me originally, but it must be a 1.3 and lower issue. For example:

```
public function beforeFilter(){
    parent::beforeFilter();
    $this->Paypal = $this->Components->load('Paypal');
}
```

And that's all she wrote.

Comment: That's actually the documented way of doing it: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/components.html#loading-components-on-the-fly

Answer (score 3):

Unless there's something I'm missing here, you use App::import to import a component.

I've heard you don't want to do this with models, because there are other things setup behind the scenes.  But components should be fine.

```
if( $condition ) {
 App::import( 'Component', 'MyComponent' );
 $this->MyComponent = new MyComponent();
 $this->MyComponent->method();
}
```

HTH,
Travis

Comment: I tried the above method. The complication is that this component makes heavy use an initialize() callback that (I think) does stuff before the controller loads. So before the users controller loads, the component logs into Facebook, and then in the beforeFilter of your controller you can then set the viewVars with user info.

Comment: Gotcha.  Sorry I can't be of more help, I'm not familiar with either the component or tying Cake into FB apps.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is late, but for anyone else searching for how to do this you need to add it in your __construct before you call the Parent's __construct.

So you'd do something like this:

```
function __construct(){
  if($thisIsTrue){
    $this->components[] = 'Facebook.Connect'
  }
  parent::__construct();
}
```

You can either do this in your individual controllers or in app_controller so every controller picks it up.

The one problem I had with this was the because it's called so early it's difficult to get variables for the if() statement. In my example I only wanted a component if I was on an admin page and instead of being able to check $this->params, I had to check the URL from $_SERVER.

I found this solution here, but it said you had to do this in app_controller which isn't the case:
[Conditional Component Loading in CakePHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3999258/conditional-component-loading-in-cakephp)

Comment: Yep, this works well, except in Cake 2.1 that I'm using I had to pass the constructor parameters to the parent, eg...
`    function __construct($request = null, $response = null) {
  $this->components[] = 'RequestHandler';  
  parent::__construct($request, $response);
 }`

Answer (score 0):

**try this in your controller**

```
var $components = array("Email", "Session", 'RequestHandler', 'Cookie');
```